# How to dynamically add UserControl to a Form in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. 
I have `Form1` and `Form2` and `UserControl1`. I want to dynamically add the `UserControl1` to `Form2` and show `Form2` using `ShowDialog` but `Form2` is shown empty. I know I can add `UserControl1` to `Form2` using `Form2` constructor but I want to do it form `Form1`.

Anyone knows how to do it?

This code is in Form1:

```
UserControl1 _UserControl1 = new UserControl1();

using (Form2 _Form2= new Form2 ())
 {

 _Form2.Controls.Add(_UserControl1);

 _Form2.ShowDialog();
  // Form2 is shown empty
 }
```

Comment: Without seeing your user control its hard to say. Do a test. Change the Add _UserControl to  "Add(new TextBox()) and see if the textbox shows. If so, it could be a property of your user control thats the problem.

Comment: Also, make sure you position the new control, also where are you doing this code?  IE where is it called from?

Answer (score 0):

When creating controls at runtime, make sure the new control has all the necessary properties set.  **Location** and **Size** are important, the control may be drawing off the form, or be tiny.

Also, make sure the control is not being hidden by another control.  Make sure the **Visible** property is set true, and that there are no panels or other controls in the area that was specified for the control to be.

If there are other controls on the form, you can try setting the control's z-index using **_Form2.Controls.SetChildIndex(_UserControl,0);**  Alternatively, if the control is intended to be on a panel, add the control to the panel's Controls collection.